# Php mysqli - How to reconnect to an updated database instance?

Tags: php, mysqli, database-connection

I'm using PHP with a DigitalOcean Managed Database cluster with a standby node. If the main node fails DigitalOcean automatically promotes the standby node, and then builds a new standby node.

Their documentation [says](https://docs.digitalocean.com/products/databases/#resilient-server-reconnection):

> To maintain availability, you should configure your client applications to attempt reconnection a reasonable number of times before timing out and causing a service disruption.

When the node fails and is replaced by DigitalOcean, PHP continues trying to connect to the old node (including in new page requests) until I do `service php8.0fpm restart`

If I ping the hostname it has updated to a new IP address.

This is my connection method:

```
public static function connectToDatabase(string $dbHostName, string $dbUserName, string $dbPassword, string $databaseName): void
{
    if (\SqlClass::$connObj) {
        $hasConnected = true;
    } else {
        \SqlClass::$connObj = mysqli_init();
        \SqlClass::$connObj->options(MYSQLI_OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, 1);
        $hasConnected = \SqlClass::$connObj->real_connect($dbHostName, $dbUserName, $dbPassword, $databaseName, 128);
        if (!$hasConnected) {
            // Try a second time, after waiting 1 secs to allow database to become available again.
            sleep(1);
            $hasConnected = \SqlClass::$connObj->real_connect($dbHostName, $dbUserName, $dbPassword, $databaseName, 128);
            if (!$hasConnected) {
                // Try a third time, after waiting 10 secs to allow database to become available again.
                sleep(10);
                \SqlClass::$connObj->options(MYSQLI_OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, 10);
                $hasConnected = \SqlClass::$connObj->real_connect($dbHostName, $dbUserName, $dbPassword, $databaseName, 128);
            }
        }
    }
    if (!$hasConnected || \SqlClass::$connObj->connect_errno) {
        // Do error handling.
        exit;
    }
    \SqlClass::$connObj->select_db($databaseName);
    \SqlClass::$connObj->options(MYSQLI_OPT_INT_AND_FLOAT_NATIVE, true);
    \SqlClass::$connObj->set_charset('utf8mb4');
}
```

It feels like PHP is using 1 or 2 shared connections between all page requests, and I need to update that somehow.

Any ideas how to tell PHP to use the new node?

Comment: What is the value of `$dbHostName`?

Comment: PHP applications are generally not persistent daemons and therefore do not maintain persistent connections to the database. A request is made, a PHP process is spun up to service that request, and then that process is terminated. If the DB connection is lost during the scope of a single request the simplest option is to simply let the request fail and have the client retry. The connection to the failed-over server should then go through. Otherwise you basically need to wrap just about any DB call in a try/catch or equivalent that will catch a broken DB connection, reestablish, and retry.

Comment: @Dharman `$dbHostName` is the VPN domain provided by DigitalOcean, something like `private-dbname-do-user-1234567-0.a.db.ondigitalocean.com` and resolves to a `10.x.x.x` address (pinging that from the command line returns the new IP address, but maybe within php it's cached the dns results?)

Comment: @Sammitch Yeah, I agree - letting the request fail and have the user reload their page is what I would like to happen, but all the new page requests keep using the old node until I restart php :-(

Comment: Then either that' `SqlClass` is doing something inadvisable, or the local DNS resolution is caching the old IP. PHP doesn't cache DNS responses, but the local resolver might.

Comment: Nvm, this code is from `SqlClass` , isn't it? [note: use `self::` rather than rewriting the class name a squillion times] Then the "something inadvisable" would be prepending `p:` onto the hostname, which enables persistent connections, which are generally inadvisable without good reason.

Comment: Thanks @Sammitch, not prepending `p:` for persistent connections, so I guess if the sql side of things is correct I'll look into the DNS more.